# using nodes to replicate gimp's grain extract mode

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I am not getting the same results as Gimp.  I checked out Github and the formula for the Blend Mode is

[blendModeKeys.GRAIN_EXTRACT]: (i, m) => (
i - m + 0.5 )

I used MixRGB Nodes and got results identical to doing the same thing in Gimp using Subtract and Add Blend Modes.  I tried to separate the channels and do the math but it looks washed out. I tried clamping and not clamping, I used SeparateRGB and SeparateXYZ and the results are the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share the blend file? https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Are you sure you're subtracting the [correct layer from the other](https://imgur.com/a/PMnkL0K)? Is it possible you're subtracting the "lower" layer from the "upper" layer?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  You need to set the Image Texture Nodes from sRGB to either Linear, Raw, or Non-color.  At the end of the equation you stick in a Gamma Node and set it anywhere between 2.2 to 2.5.  You can use the Add and Subract Blend modes in MixRGB and you will get the same result.